# How to rebuild a web project from a .war file?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, web-applications, war

I have only the .war file and i want to rebuild the project so i can open it with netbeans or eclipse to modify the web app

is it possible?

I tried to decompress the war and found some things:

[war decompress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDaWh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily modify the front end code (js, jsp, css, html, etc.), but if the source code for the back end was not included into war file (it usually is not), then your only option in modifying back end is to decompile code, create a project, make your changes, and rebuild all. It would be easier if the changes you want to make are small. Further advice depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code of the compiled file, yes.

Basically, you can create a empty web project and copy the content over.

I am using Eclipse Luna as example, 
In eclipse, click, File --> New --> Web Project.
Select a Simple and Web Module in the wizard panels.

Once the project is created, copy the content of the 'META-INF' and 'WEB-INF' folder into 'WebContent/META-INF' and 'WebContent/WEB-INF' according.

If there is Java Source file, it goes into the "Java Resources/src" folder, with the correct folder structure based on the package name.

The rest go to the root of the project, but you may want to ignore the '.' file and folders

You may still have some compile errors and you will need to fix them accordingly.